# Explanation for sprintf("%03d", 7) functionality?

Tags: r, csv, printf, paste

I am trying to write functions in R where the aim is to read multiple .csv files. They are named as 001.csv, 002.csv, ... 332.csv.

With `paste` I managed to construct names 1.csv, 2.csv and so on, but I'm having difficulty with adding leading zeroes. There's a hint that the construction like `sprintf("%03d", 7)` is required, but I have no idea why and how this works.

So can somebody explain what the following statement can actually does?

Comment: Did you read the `?sprintf` help page? Was there a specific part that was unclear to you?

Answer (score 53):

`sprintf` originally comes from C and all formatting rules are taken from it as well. See `?sprintf` in R or [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) or [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) reference to learn the subject in detail. Here I'll briefly outline what's the magic behind it.

`"%03d"` is a formatting string, which specifies how `7` will be printed.

- `d` stands for `decimal integer` (not `double`!), so it says there will be no floating point or anything like that, just a regular integer.
- `3` shows how many digits will the printed number have. More precisely, the number will take *at least* 3 digits: `7` will be `__7` (with spaces instead of underscores), but `1000` will remain `1000`, as there is no way to write this number with just 3 digits.
- `0` before `3` shows that leading spaces should be replaced by zeroes. Try experimenting with `sprintf("%+3d", 7)`, `sprintf("%-3d", 7)` to see other possible modifiers (they are called *flags*).

That being said, the output from `sprintf("%03d", 7)` will be `007`.

Comment: @Aron Thanks -- always a pleasure!

Comment: This really helped me with something other than `R`. It's great that you explained what `0`, `3`, and `d` each do, and not just what `03d` does.

Answer (score 1):

03d will print minimum 3 digit output...if then the output is less than 3 digit it will add zeros in beginning.If output is more than single 3 digits it will simply print output.
if output(%d)= 2,
with %3d will will be printed as = 002