# how can i print zero at the first of output

Tags: c, printing, whitespace, zero

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int Phone_number1,Phone_number2,Phone_number3 ; 
  printf("Enter phone number [(xxx) xxx-xxxx]: ");
  scanf("(%d) %d-%d" , &Phone_number1 , &Phone_number2 , &Phone_number3);
  
   printf("you entered: %d.%d.%d ",Phone_number1,Phone_number2,Phone_number3 );
  return 0;
}
```

```
Enter phone number [(xxx) xxx-xxxx]: (010) 7568-5230 // this was my input
```

`you entered: 10.7568.5230 // this was my out put`

[`display user phone number`](https://replit.com/@kjinhub/Display-user-phone-number#main.c)  `//my code`

but i wanted to print like this 010.7568.5230

i don't find it out where is zero at the first of output

*i think zero is same role as white space during computing so the first zero couldn't show up in my output*

Comment: Try `%03d.%04d.%04d` instead of `%d.%d.%d` when you `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` in C has formatting rules. [Click_here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for reference in regards to understanding `printf` in detail. Here I'll briefly outline with respect to your question.

"`%03d %04d`" is a formatting in `printf` will specify how your phone number will be printed.

- `d` stands for decimal integer (not double!), so it says there will be
  no floating point or anything like that, just a regular integer.
- `3` shows how many digits will the printed number have. More precisely,
  the number will take at least 3 digits: 010 will be 10 but adding 3
  will place zero at the start. (similar is case for `%04d`
- `0` before 3 shows that leading spaces should be replaced by zeroes.

Check similar explanation for [sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718936/explanation-for-sprintf03d-7-functionality).

Modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int Phone_number1,Phone_number2,Phone_number3 ; 
  printf("Enter phone number [(xxx) xxx-xxxx]: ");
  scanf("(%d) %d-%d" , &Phone_number1 , &Phone_number2 , &Phone_number3);
  printf("you entered: %03d.%04d.%04d ",Phone_number1,Phone_number2,Phone_number3 );
  return 0;
}
```